# looping html input values (with python)

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am trying to display records, and then allow the user to view a specific record. The records are gathered with python. 
When a user clicks on the application ID of a specific record I want to store the application ID in order to use it to query more details of the record.

I have an loop where all the records gathered from python are displayed in an html table. The application ID for each record appears correctly. But when I try store the data by clicking the button of the application ID it is always storing the application ID of the first record that is displayed. For instance, the first app ID is 3, and the second is 13. If I click on 13, it will store 3.
Not sure why this occurs because it is being displayed correctly. I have attached an image of is occurring.
Any help would be much appreciated.

My HTML:

```
<tbody>
              {% for row in rows %}
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type='button' name="number" id = 'number' type="submit" onclick="initStorage()" value = {{row.id}} ></input>
                  </td>
                  <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ row.email }}</td>
                  <td>{{ row.phone }}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

My Javascript:

```
[<script type = 'text/javascript'>
  function initStorage() {
    function saveNumber() {
      var number = document.getElementById('number');
      localStorage.setItem('number', number.value);
      alert(localStorage.getItem('number'));
    }
    saveNumber();
  }

</script>][1]
```

[Photo of issue: select application 13, but it wants to store 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJzHC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
[<script type = 'text/javascript'>
      function initStorage(val) {
        function saveNumber() {          
          localStorage.setItem('number', val);
          alert(localStorage.getItem('number'));
        }
        saveNumber();
      }
    
    </script>]
```

```html
<tbody>
                  {% for row in rows %}
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input type='button' name="number" id = 'number' type="submit" onclick="initStorage({{row.id}})" value = {{row.id}} ></input>
                      </td>
                      <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ row.email }}</td>
                      <td>{{ row.phone }}</td>
                    </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

I made your code a little easier to understand.This way you are directly passing the value when the button has been pressed no need to access it through jquery now.

Another possible solution for you is to use a class instead of `id='number'` ie. `class='number'` and access it via a click in jquery only without an onclick function like this

```
$('.number').on('click',function(){
     var number = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` tag [represents a unique element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). Even though your code is correctly updating the `value` attribute, there's still only one element registered in the DOM as `number`. This registration is taking the value of the first element rendered as `id="number"` (which in this case is 3).

Use `this` as an argument to `initStorage()` to get the properties of the clicked element, rather than searching for the element inside `saveNumber()`.  Also, give unique IDs to each element - you can programmatically add a suffix to do this (there are a lot of other ways as well). Even if you don't end up referencing elements by `id` in this section, it's still good practice to keep your `id` tags unique.

Here's a Fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/kwu7oLju/